# GET Unique List from different classes using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 classes with different properties

```
ClassA
    int Id
    int Name
    int Status

ClassB
    int ClassAId
    string Bprop1
    string Bprop2
    string Bprop3
    ...
```

I have List of ClassA and List of ClassB and i want to get a unique list of ClassA values with the condition

> List where ClassA.Id is present with List on property ClassAId

Example:

```
// given
List<ClassA>  {{1,"a"},{2,"b"},{3,"c"},{4,"d"}} etc
Lisst<ClassB>  {{1,"aaa","ccc","aasdaf"},{3,"aaa","ccc","aasdaf"}}

// expected result
List<ClassA>  {{1,"a"},{3,"c"}}
```

How can I apply a LINQ query for the same?

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the expected output:-

```
List<ClassA> resultClassA = classAObj.Where(a => classBObj.Any(b => b.ClassAId == a.Id))
                                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you're looking for:

```
List<ClassA> objA;
List<ClassB> objB;

List<ClassA> result = objA.Where(x => objB.Select(y => y.ClassAId).Contains(x.Id));
```

Don't forget to define your `objA` and `objB` with data.

If you have dublicate values in `objA` you should just use `.Distinct()` at the end.